# How to use pandas.merge with some tolerance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to compare two pandas dataframes and merge the results with some tolerancing of the values. For example, I have two dataframes that have x-, y-position, and frame number. I want to merge these if the frame number is equal and the x- and y-values are within a range of 3.0. Just using pandas.merge requires the x- and y-values to be the exact same. Is there a way to have some tolerance built in to this merging function?

Comment: Look for merge_asof. But I think it only work for one coordinate, not two. Otherwise you need to calculate the distance matrix and filter manually.

Comment: kindly share sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.merge_asof`:

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, ..., tolerance=3.0)
```

Comment: As commented, I don’t think merger_asof works for two keys. Merge twice might work if the tolerance is meant to applied on x and y separately. It wouldn’t work for, say Euclidean distance.